# @OneToOne делает sql запрос на каждый объект в таблице

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Всем привет, сделал необходимые entity под БД:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "****", schema = "****")
public class ShopProductEntity implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sku_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ShopProductSkusEntity sku;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "****", schema = "*****")
public class ShopProductSkusEntity implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer productId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sku", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String sku;
}
```

И когда делаю запрос на получение всех элементов таблицы:

```
public synchronized List<ShopProductEntity> getAllProducts() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ShopProductEntity a", ShopProductEntity.class)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

То вижу по логам Hibernate, что происходит первый запрпос на получение всех строк из ShopProductEntity, а потом для каждой записи - происходит отдельный запрос в ShopProductSkusEntity:

```
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_4_, shopproduc0_.sku_id as sku_id2_4_ from shop_product shopproduc0_
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
Hibernate: select shopproduc0_.id as id1_7_0_, shopproduc0_.product_id as product_2_7_0_, shopproduc0_.sku as sku3_7_0_ from shop_product_skus shopproduc0_ where shopproduc0_.id=?
и так далее . . .
```

А записей в ShopProductEntity порядка 180000 и Hibernate делает запросы не паралельно, а в одном потоке. И каждый запрос занимает где-то 0.2-0.3 мс, что приводит к неопределенному кол-во времени в ожидании, пока всё выгрузиться (явно более 1 часа).

**Вопрос:**
Как оптимизировать этот момент?
Может как-то можно указать Hibernate, чтобы он кэшировал сразу всю таблицу ShopProductSkusEntity и не обращался постоянно к БД?
Или есть какие-то другие варианты, может это проблема N+1 и надо копать в эту сторону?

Comment: есть несколько вопросов: 1) зачем вам вообще потребовался запрос типа findAll? если в бд будет таблица на 3 тб будуте память докупать? может вы что-то слышали про пагинацию? 2) с какой целью вы добавляете связь onetoone, если вам необходимы все данные?

Comment: @Дмитрий
1) Правильно ли я вас понимаю, что вы предлагаете доставать данные пачками, условно говоря по 1000 штук? Если да - то что поменяется, все равно будет происходить доп.запрос на каждую строку, нет разве?
2) Добавил т.к. 1 строка ShopProductEntity ссылается на одну строку ShopProductSkusEntity, по идее это связь один к одному или я что-то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: 1)я предлагаю исходить из здравого смысла, а он подсказывает что есть 2 варианта развития событий: а)данные нужны пользователю и тогда ему точно не нужны все, потому что человек это переварить не мпособен, прикручиваем пагинацию и отдаем постраничо; б)дангные нужны для какого-то анализа и бла-бла-бла, тогда это асинхронный процесс (может, к примеру запускаться в худшем случае по крону), опять же берем их постранично и обрабатываем порциями, дабы память не закончилась. никакой из вариантов не предусматривает выгрузки всех данных из базы в память

Comment: 2) да, это связь один к одному. поэтому вы получаете запись, а потом вторым запросом запись, на которую ссылается связь. и я вам говорю о том, что с точки зоения джавы, как языка программирования, связь один к одному - жуткий костыль в угоду бд. а в ситуации, когда вам всегда нужны все данные (включая данные по связи), какой смысл крутить костыль со стороны джавы и грузить доп запросом бд? в этом случае расчет на lazy, т.е на то, что джанные нужны далеко не всегда, но, судя по всему , это не ваш случай.может тогда целесообразно объединить эти две сущности в одну? никаких связей и доп запросов?

Comment: Можно получить все данные одним запросом через join `"SELECT a FROM ShopProductEntity a left join fetch a.sku"`, тогда вся нагрузка ляжет на БД. Зависит от индексов в этих таблицах, отработает очень быстро.  Если нужно вытащить только ShopProductEntity  без связки со второй сущностью, то аннотация должна выглядеть `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.  Я бы отказался от использования OneToOne, т.к. его сложно поддерживать, если у Вас не самая последния версия hibernate и есть наследники этой сущности. Если есть возможность, замените на `@ManyToOne`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из комментариев под вопросом (спасибо Дмитрию и MrFylypenko) - выявил 2 решения, которые одинаково хорошо решают мою проблему:

1. Принудительно использовать в HQL запросе left join fetch, что заставить Hibernate добавить в свой запрос left outer join и сразу выгрузить все необходимые строки из другой таблицы, вместо того чтобы делать отдельный запрос на каждую строку
2. Просто использовать @ManyToOne